# CSS - 100% opaque table cells over 95% opacity background image

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Given a page body has a boldly coloured background image set, and then a canvas `<div>` section inside that has a background colour of pure white (`#FFFFFF`) and an opacity of 95% so that you can just see the image showing through faint like a watermark, is it possible with CSS to set the background of cells in a table within the canvas section to have the white background but fully opaque with no background image showing through behind the data in the cells?

So far I've tried setting `opacity: 1;` on the *table*, *tr*, and *td* elements, and also tried setting a new `background-image: url('white.png');` expecting it to tile the 1px by 1px white image I made over the cell background, however neither of these approaches seems to work.

Has anyone successfully managed to achieve this before?

Comment: I'm not sure why StackOverflow would be better suited for this question than Webmasters?

Comment: Because we're about the content and scripts, webmasters the more technical stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `opacity`  on the div because that affects all the content inside and isn't reversible for the child elements ... Instead use an [**`rgba()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()) value for the white background:

> rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)

Where `.3` is the opacity value for the background-color.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports');
}
div {
  height:50%;
  width:70%;
  margin:auto;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  padding:30px;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  line-height:90px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works brilliantly, thank you Danko. I'd forgotten all about the rgba function!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="opacity">
    <div id="no-opacity">content</div>
</div>
```

If You set `opacity: .5` to `#opacity` element, it's no possible to restore this opacity to `opacity: 1` on `#no-opacity` element

If that's what are You asking about.

Comment: Hi Michal, Yes essentially. I'm aware that the opacity CSS property cannot be overridden from a child node, that's why I'm looking for an alternative method to achieve this.

Comment: Your table has to be inside main div with background?? Can't You position it in other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RGBA (Red,Blue,Green,Alpha=opacity)](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/).

```css
body{  background: blue url('//lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/'); }
#Wrap{ background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.95); padding: 25px; }
```

```html
<div id="Wrap">
    <table>
        <tr><td> Example, I'm 100% visible! </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But does it work with background-image instead of background-color??

Comment: @MichałKutra check the snippet on my answer you can see that works...this code just make the background of element transparent so it will work over any element.

Comment: But when You add for example: background-image: url('//lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/'); to #Wrap there will be no opacity on image from background

Comment: The image is in the body, the wrap is is your content wrapper